# Store Spark df to HBase

Tags: java, sql, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to store a Spark DataSet to HBase in an efficient way. When we tried to do something like that with a lambda in JAVA :

```
sparkDF.foreach(l->this.hBaseConnector.persistMappingToHBase(l,"name_of_hBaseTable") );
```

The function persistMappingtoHBase uses the HBase Java client (Put) to store in HBase.

```
I get an exception: Exception in thread "main"  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
```

Then we tried this:

```
sparkDF.foreachPartition(partition -> {
    final HBaseConnector hBaseConnector = new HBaseConnector();
    hBaseConnector.connect(hbaseProps);
    while (partition.hasNext()) {
        hBaseConnector.persistMappingToHBase(partition.next());
    }
    hBaseConnector.closeConnection();
});
```

which seems to be working but it seems quite inefficient, I guess because we create and close a connection for each row of the dataframe.

What is a good way to store a spark DS to HBase ? I saw [a connector developed by IBM](https://github.com/IBM/sparksql-for-hbase?cm_sp=Developer-_-use-spark-sql-to-access-nosql-hbase-tables-_-Get-the-Code)  but never used it.

Comment: We have a pretty fast connector at Splice Machine that writes Data Frames natively into hbase.  I believe we are the fastest writer to HBase still...  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgIz-cjehJ0&t=3s

Comment: thanks, if time allows, I will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

The following can be used to save the content to HBase

```
val hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create
hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
hbaseConfig.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")

val job = Job.getInstance(hbaseConfig)
job.setOutputFormatClass(classOf[TableOutputFormat[_]])
job.getConfiguration.set(TableOutputFormat.OUTPUT_TABLE, "test_table")

val result = sparkDF.map(row -> {
    //  Using UUID as my rowkey, you can use your own rowkey
    val put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(UUID.randomUUID().toString))

    //  setting the value of each row to Put object
    ....
    ....

    new Tuple2[ImmutableBytesWritable, Put](new ImmutableBytesWritable(), put)
});

//  save result to hbase table
result.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(job.getConfiguration)
```

I have following dependencies in my `build.sbt` file

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "1.3.0"
```